# cannot ping a single device through route

Tags: routing, ip

I have the following topology:

```
           /- D1
G1 -- G2 <
           \- D2
```

G2.eth0 (10.0.0.105) is on the same network as G1.eth1 (10.0.0 network). G1 can ping G2 and visa-versa.

D1 and D2 are connectable via G2.eth1 (203.0.113 network). G2 can ping both.

On G1 I have set up a route adding the 203 network from G2:

```
ip route add 203.0.113.0/24 via 10.0.0.105 dev eth1
```

G1 can ping D1 on 203.0.113.4

**however, G1 cannot ping D2 on 203.0.113.25**

What should I check?

Answer (score 1):

D2 didn't have a default route. adding this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the route to G2 instead of making it on D1